# Can I use the data within a cell as a sheet reference within a formula?

Tags: excel

I have a table that looks like the following -

A | Name1 |                |

B | Name2 |               |

C | Name3 |               |

D | Name4 |               |

I  then also have 4 more sheets, each called Name1, Name2, Name3 and Name4.

In column 2 I would like content to auto populate from each of the sheets with a total that is found on the relating sheet. I am using this to achieve this in column B2 (The data I need to show in B2 is located in M4 on the Name1 sheet) - =('Name1'!M4)

Is there a way I can use A1 as a reference instead of the sheet name? This is so as new columns are added to the above table, providing the new sheet is named the same the formula can just be dragged down and auto-populated (The total I need will always be in M4 on every new sheet).

I've hoped I've explained this well enough, I have played around with =INDIRECT however to no avail.

Many Thanks

Comment: please show your attempt using INDIRECT.  It is the only way to do this.

Comment: Hi Scott, I've done the following:   '=('=INDIRECT(A1)'!M4) thanks

Comment: INDIRECT changes a string to a valid reference.  so you need to create a concatenated string: `=INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!M4")`

Comment: If you only have four sheets to consider then it may be worth avoiding the volatile `INDIRECT`, for example: `=CHOOSE(MATCH(A1,{"Name1";"Name2";"Name3";"Name4"},0),Name1!M4,Name2!M4,Name3!M4,Name4!M4)`

Comment: @ScottCraner Fantastic, worked first time, I knew there was something I was missing and thanks for explanation too! Do you want to do an answer so I can mark it as correct? I'm not sure if that is of any benefit to you? Thanks again!

Comment: @JosWoolley at that point you might as well just do `=Name1!M4`, etc.  The idea the OP wants is `This is so as new columns are added to the above table, providing the new sheet is named the same the formula can just be dragged down and auto-populated` your formula would require changing it every time a new sheet is added.  Also 15 to 20 INDIRECTS pointed at a single cell will not put a noticeable drag on the calcs